# group by sum of products of child model attributes

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, scope

```
Document has_many :items

Item belongs_to :document
```

I need to find documents, in which the sum of products of its `items.quantity * items.value_net` is greater than certain value.

I tried scope:

```
scope :items_value_net_gteq, lambda { |value|
  joins(:items)
    .where('SUM(items.quantity * items.price_net) >= ?', value)
}
```

But it is wrong. I must be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `having` (not tested):

```
scope :items_value_net_gteq, ->(value) {
  joins(:items).group('documents.id').
    having('SUM(items.quantity * items.price_net) >= ?', value)
}
```

Comment: works like charm, +1 and accept (10 seconds difference, but still first to answer)

Answer (score 2):

```
scope :items_value_net_gteq, lambda do |value|
  joins(:items).group("items.document_id")
         .having('SUM(items.quantity * items.price_net) >= ?', value)
end
```

Comment: thanks a bunch! upvoted but will have to accept @BroiState's answer, - he was "first" :D